# 301 Redirects -- old pages with /? at start not working (Joomla 3)

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

Our old site had all its urls starting with "/?" . I have now created a Joomla 3 site, and registered all the old urls with a 301 to the new in our htaccess.  However, the 301 Redirects are not working....

e.g.
Redirect 301 /?old-page /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=78&Itemid=999

Instead, all my redirects go to our Home page.

Any suggestions?

thanks
Geoff

Comment: I suggest you edit your post to show what your .htaccess file looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^old-page$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=78&Itemid=999 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I notice that using this rule seems to send the page to the non-sef url.  The site is set for SEF urls.  Do you know if there is a way to use the same Joomla link structure as per the example above, but result in a sef url?

Comment: @Geoff just replace the `/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=78&Itemid=999` bit with the SEF url and add a `?` at the end

Comment: OK, thanks.  I have about 100 301 redirects ready to go with their joomla url... is there an easy way to use the redirect which gets converted to the SEF?

Comment: @Geoff depends on what the "old-page" looks like and if that maps directory to the structure of the joomla url

Comment: It seems that the solution above, while it works, appends the original parameter to the redirect. e.g.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^library/mybook
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mydomain.com/library/catalog/book15 [R=301,L]

ends up going to 
http://www.mydomain.com/library/catalog/book15?library/mybook

How to fix?

thanks again,

Comment: @Geoff add a `?` to the end of the target URL: `http://www.mydomain.com/library/catalog/book15?`